# Request attributes

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a page, and there are 3 types of button(apple,banana, orange), by clicking the first button, a form comes up to get information. The first button should send information to the apple Model, the banana button should send information to the banana Model and so orange!

here is my models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Apple(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Banana(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Orange(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

my forms.py:

```
from django import forms

class Fruit(forms.Form):
   first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
```

my views.py:

```
def fruitForm(request):
    form = Fruit()
    if request.method == 'POST' & request.id == 'apple':
          form = Fruit(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
                  Apple.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
     elif request.method =='POST' & request.id =='orange':
          form = Fruit(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
                  Orange.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
     elif request.method =='POST' & request.id =='banana':
          form = Fruit(request.POST)
          if form.is_valid():
                  Banana.objects.create(**form.cleaned_data)
     return render(request, 'main/home.html', {'form':form})
```

my home.html:

```
<button class='btn btn-primary' data-target='#orange'> Add </button>
<form action=# method="POST" id = "orange">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{ form.as_p }}
</form>
```

well, when I try go to main page (where the buttons are), I got this error:
'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'id'.
request doesn't have the id attribute, right? So, How can I get specific data to save in relative model?

Comment: Not your question, but the boolean and operator in Python is `and`, not `&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `name` to a submit input, the value is the text content of the button so cannot really be used for this

```
<form>
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="orange" value="Add">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="apple" value="Add">
</form>
```

This value will then be one of the keys in the post data

```
if 'orange' in request.POST:
    pass
elif 'apple' in request.POST:
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

The attributes of the `POST` request body come from the `name` attributes of the form inputs. So one way to handle this, if you want to keep your view function the same, is to add a hidden field to each form that distinguishes which model it should update:

```
<form action=# method="POST" id = "orange">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="orange" />
 {{ form.as_p }}
</form>
```

And similarly for the other 2 forms.

(This isn't the only way to solve this problem. You could, for example, have a variable in your URL which specifies which model to use. Then you could check its value in your view function. This requires a bit more work though, including changing your `urls.py`.)